# How to read timezone id from GET-TIMEZONE function response in powershell

Tags: powershell, timezone

I am new to powershell, so do not know what is the best way to read id of timezone from the `GET-TIMEZONE` function response in powershell.

The function returns response in this format

[image]

I want to read the `Id` value. Which is `India Standard Time` in this example.

Any leads?

Comment: Just put the cmdlet in between brackets and use a dot to add the property you need `(Get-TimeZone).Id`, OR use `Get-TimeZone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id`

Comment: @Theo - you could post that as an answer please?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint You're right, it is better to answer by posting an answer instead of doing that in a comment. I sometimes feel it is too trivial to post, but that would mean yet another question on SO lives on as 'unanswered'. Posted now.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by [Matt Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson-pint) here my comment as answer.

The [Get-TimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-timezone) cmdlet returns the current time zone or a list of available time zones. Without using parameters, it returns the timezone for the local computer.

The returned value(s) are always **object(s)** with properties as shown in the OPs screenshot.
If you want the value of just one of these properties. you can use either the dot syntax

```
(Get-TimeZone).Id
```

which because of the brackets, makes PowerShell execute the cmdlet first and from that returned object, you pick the apropriate property to get its value.

Another way is to use `Select-Object` and expand the property you need in order to receive the value only like this:

```
Get-TimeZone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
```

Without parameter `-ExpandProperty`, this will return a new **object** with one property named `Id`.

Objects usually also have methods besides properties. To show these, you can pipe the result through to another cmdlet called `Get-Member` (or `gm` for short)

```
Get-TimeZone | Get-Member *  # using the asteriks, the cmdlet returns all members
```

which results in

```
Name                       MemberType Definition                                                                                                
----                       ---------- ----------                                                                                                
Equals                     Method     bool Equals(System.TimeZoneInfo other), bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool IEquatable[TimeZoneInfo].E...
GetAdjustmentRules         Method     System.TimeZoneInfo+AdjustmentRule[] GetAdjustmentRules()                                                 
GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets    Method     timespan[] GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(System.DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset), timespan[] GetAmbiguousTimeOf...
GetHashCode                Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                         
GetObjectData              Method     void ISerializable.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Se...
GetType                    Method     type GetType()                                                                                            
GetUtcOffset               Method     timespan GetUtcOffset(System.DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset), timespan GetUtcOffset(datetime dateTime)     
HasSameRules               Method     bool HasSameRules(System.TimeZoneInfo other)                                                              
IsAmbiguousTime            Method     bool IsAmbiguousTime(System.DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset), bool IsAmbiguousTime(datetime dateTime)       
IsDaylightSavingTime       Method     bool IsDaylightSavingTime(System.DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset), bool IsDaylightSavingTime(datetime dat...
IsInvalidTime              Method     bool IsInvalidTime(datetime dateTime)                                                                     
OnDeserialization          Method     void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(System.Object sender)                                     
ToSerializedString         Method     string ToSerializedString()                                                                               
ToString                   Method     string ToString()                                                                                         
BaseUtcOffset              Property   timespan BaseUtcOffset {get;}                                                                             
DaylightName               Property   string DaylightName {get;}                                                                                
DisplayName                Property   string DisplayName {get;}                                                                                 
Id                         Property   string Id {get;}                                                                                          
StandardName               Property   string StandardName {get;}                                                                                
SupportsDaylightSavingTime Property   bool SupportsDaylightSavingTime {get;}
```